# How to add filetype to meta value when using wp_upload_bits?

Tags: uploads, attachments

I've set up a custom post type and would like to have the ability to attach files to those posts. I've got the CPT and metabox set up, and the upload function as well.

When I display the CPT on the front end, I'd like there to be a download link for the file. To simplify things, I'd like to use the included MIME type icons (`wp-includes/images/crystal/document.png` for example). Using `wp_upload_bits()` there's no MIME in the meta array.

Is it possible to add the MIME type to the function? Or should I be looking at another function/method of identifying the MIME?

Here's my upload code:

```
 $upload = wp_upload_bits($_FILES['resources_attachment']['name'], null, file_get_contents($_FILES['resources_attachment']['tmp_name']));

 if(isset($upload['error']) && $upload['error'] != 0) {
   wp_die('There was an error uploading your file. The error is: ' . $upload['error']);
 } else {
 add_post_meta($id, 'resources_attachment', $upload);
 update_post_meta($id, 'resources_attachment', $upload);       
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using `wp_handle_upload()`, which puts MIME type into the DB automatically. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload

One thing to note, this function enters the file in the DB as post meta and not as an attachment. `wp_insert_attachment()` would do the latter.